# Value of a created UserControl Dependency Property never changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controls, dependency-properties

I created a dependency property in my user control and I want to send his value to my View Model. I want to set the value of my user control in a TestWindow like this. `<local:CompanySearch ShowEmployeesTest="True"/>`
But the value of my property does not change. Where is my mistake? Can someone help me.

```
   Public Shared ReadOnly ShowEmployeesProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowEmployeesTest", GetType(Boolean), GetType(CompanySearch))

Public Property ShowEmployeesTest() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ShowEmployeesProperty), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(ShowEmployeesProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: "But the value of my property does not change". Do you mean that your Set method isn't called? That is because WPF may directly call SetValue when the property is set in XAML, or by a binding or by a couple of other sources. Besides that the naming convention for the DependencyProperty field is `<property-name>Property`, so yours should be `ShowEmployeesTestProperty`.

Comment: Now I try to use the property changed callback function but it is shared Sub. How can I got the DataContext of my usercontrol in this sub?

Comment: The first parameter to the PropertyChangedCallback is the UserControl instance as DependencyObject, so you have to cast it to your UserControl type. The second parameter gives you the old and new property values.